# sprite not showing up in pygame & invalid rectstyle object

Tags: python, pygame

I am following a tutorial on PyGame and in one of the tutorial we are creating a simple Space Invaders game. I have a few problems.

1. The spaceship sprite won't show on the screen, and 2. I get an error. (more details on that below)

Code:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

clock = pygame.time.Clock() #framerate

size = x,y=800,600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((size)) #creates window, with resolution of 1600,900

pygame.mouse.set_visible(0)

ship = pygame.image.load('ship.png')

ship_top = screen.get_height() - ship.get_height() #makes it so ship is in the centre at the bottom
ship_left = screen.get_width()/2 - ship.get_width()/2




while True: #main game loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    screen.fill(0,0,0)
    screen.blit(ship,(ship_left,ship_top))



    clock.tick(60)
    pygame.display.update
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\python_tuts\space_invaders.py", line 24, in <module>
    screen.fill(0,0,0)
ValueError: invalid rectstyle object
```

So the sprites do not show, and I get that error.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

The fill method looks like this:

```
fill(color, rect=None, special_flags=0) -> Rect
```

Since you are calling it like this:

```
screen.fill(0,0,0)
```

It assigns 0 to rect and special_flags. I think you meant to do this:

```
screen.fill((0,0,0))
```

It's even better to define color tuples at the start of your code

```
BLACK = (0,0,0)
screen.fill(BLACK)
```